# COBOL- Find year of Birth from age

Tags: date, cobol

I'm used the below code to find only the year of birth from age using cobol but couldn't able to convert the year into numeric variable. My code is

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. AGECONV.
DATA DIVISION.
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
01 CURR-YEAR PIC X(4) VALUES SPACES.
01 YEAR-OF-BIRTH X(4).
PROCEDURE DIVISION
MOVE FUNCTION CURRENT-DATE TO CURR-YEAR.
DISPLAY CURR-YEAR
SUBTRACT CURR-YEAR BY 22
GIVING YEAR-OF-BIRTH.
DISPLAY YEAR-OF-BIRTH.
```

I got the error that curr-year is not numeric.

Comment: Please recheck the answers and "upvote" all you find useful and "accept" the one that "worked for you". If there is none that matches this description please comment on the answers. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `SUBTRACT` the sending field, `CURR-YEAR`, needs to be numeric. It was defined as alphanumeric. This means that `CURR-YEAR` needs to be `PIC 9(4)`. The same is true of `YEAR-OF-BIRTH` which was missing the `PIC`.

`FUNCTION CURRENT-DATE` is an alphanumeric sending field. This rules for `MOVE` do not allow it to be moved directly to a numeric field. The reference modifier, `(1:4)`, was added to allow the move.

The format of the `SUBTRACT` statement was incorrect and has been changed.

Revised code:

```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID. AGECONV.
   DATA DIVISION.
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01 CURR-YEAR PIC 9(4) VALUE ZERO.
   01 YEAR-OF-BIRTH PIC 9(4).
   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   MOVE FUNCTION CURRENT-DATE (1:4) TO CURR-YEAR.
   DISPLAY CURR-YEAR
   SUBTRACT 22 FROM CURR-YEAR
   GIVING YEAR-OF-BIRTH.
   DISPLAY YEAR-OF-BIRTH.
```

Output:

```
2020
1998
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `MOVE FUNCTION CURRENT-DATE TO CURR-YEAR (1:4)`? The way it currently is written only limits the alphanumeric size to 4 byte but keeps the numeric year, doesn't it?
Note: instead of that interesting hack, I'd suggest to use a parent field:  `01 CURR-YEAR-X.  03 CURR-YEAR PIC 9(4) VALUE ZERO.`

Comment: @SimonSobisch - Either position for the reference modification will work. When after the function, it does a permissible alphanumeric to numeric move. When after the receiving field, it does an alphanumeric to alphanumeric move. I wanted to make only the minimum modifications, but I agree that your suggestion is a better style for consistency since the year only is rarely used as a destination.

Comment: please explain "When after the function, it does a permissible alphanumeric to numeric move" vs. " an alphanumeric sending field [..] rules for MOVE do not allow it to be moved directly to a numeric field."

Comment: @SimonSobisch - The "it" in my answer refers to `CURRENT-DATE`, which usually contains a "+" or "-" in the 17th position. That sign makes _it_ non-numeric. The effect is to move "0000" (or nothing) rather than the year. The first 4 positions pass the numeric test, therefore the move is permitted. The "it" in my comment refers to the reference modification.

Comment: That's interesting. So `MOVE "0000" to CURR-YEAR` would be allowed (possibly with a warning) but `MOVE "00+0" to CURR-YEAR` would?

Comment: @SimonSobisch - ISO/IEC CD2.0 1989:202x. MOVE statement, GR 6 d) "When a numeric or numeric-edited item is the receiving item," 3. "When the sending operand is described as alphanumeric ..., the sending operand is treated as if it were an unsigned integer of category numeric" a. for data item c. for literal. It's been the same for as long I remember and the receiving item may be display, binary, or packed-decimal.

Answer (score 2):

You need a more elaborate WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. AGECONV.

DATA DIVISION.
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
01  WS-CURRENT-DATE-DATA.
    05  WS-CURRENT-DATE.
        10  WS-CURRENT-YEAR         PIC 9(04).
        10  WS-CURRENT-MONTH        PIC 9(02).
        10  WS-CURRENT-DAY          PIC 9(02).
    05  WS-CURRENT-TIME.
        10  WS-CURRENT-HOURS        PIC 9(02).
        10  WS-CURRENT-MINUTE       PIC 9(02).
        10  WS-CURRENT-SECOND       PIC 9(02).
        10  WS-CURRENT-MILLISECONDS PIC 9(02).

01  YEAR-OF-BIRTH                   PIC 9(04).

PROCEDURE DIVISION.
MOVE FUNCTION CURRENT-DATE TO WS-CURRENT-DATE-DATA
DISPLAY WS-CURRENT-YEAR
SUBTRACT WS-CURRENT-YEAR BY 22 GIVING YEAR-OF-BIRTH
DISPLAY YEAR-OF-BIRTH.
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it that way, an activity was passed to display this additional information in my group

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID. AGECONV.
   DATA DIVISION.
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01 CURR-YEAR PIC 9(4) VALUE ZERO.
   01 YEAR-OF-BIRTH PIC 9(4).
   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   MOVE FUNCTION CURRENT-DATE (1:4) TO CURR-YEAR.
   SUBTRACT 1999 FROM CURR-YEAR
   GIVING YEAR-OF-BIRTH.
   DISPLAY 'Me chamo Thiago Lyra e tenho '  YEAR-OF-BIRTH  ' anos de idade'.
   DISPLAY 'Meu email é: thiago.lyra@globality.com'.
```